# How to remove seamonkey from Evolution

Tags: linux, firefox, evolution, seamonkey

I have un-installed seamonkey on CentOS according to the directions for Linux. However, when I click on a link in an Evolution email, I get this error:

```
Could not open the link.
Failed to execute child process.
"seamonkey" (no such file or directory)
```

I have located Evolution's files under ~/.gconf; searched those files; but cannot find any reference to seamonkey.

I've searched from the root of my home directory for seamonkey, and did remove a couple of references to it -- like in `preferred-web-browser.desktop` -- but the error persists. I need help to narrow down where this problem originates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved, because I removed the following files:

```
.gconf/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/%gconf.xml
.gconf/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/%gconf.xml
```

Once I removed these files, whose contents contained references to seamonkey, Evolution properly launches Firefox.